# System disk read only

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 SSDs on my PC and the OS partition is Read-only. I've unchecked *Read-only* in Properties, but it's the same when I reload.  Due to this, I'm unable to save any Origin games on `C:\`, as it tells me it's Read-only (my user is an Administrator account).

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use diskpart:

Step 1: Click on your "Start Menu", type cmd in the search bar, then hit "Enter".

Step 2: Type command diskpart and hit "Enter". A new command line window will open.

Step 3: Type list disk and hit "Enter". (make sure your devices has been listed out, for example, it is listed as disk 0)

Step 4: Type the command select disk 0 and hit "Enter".

Step 5: Type attributes disk clear readonly and hit "Enter".

Src:[EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-to-read-write-and-format.html)

Comment: Diskpart tells me that he doesn't delete attributes of the disk

Comment: Make sure you use Diskpart as Administrator and the disk isn't hidden and has a drive letter assigned. If this is already done, maybe some bad sectors cause the problem. Run chkdsk `C: /c` to check and repair those sectors.

Comment: All is okay for Windows. No bad sectors

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the permissions set on the C drive? Normally, YOURCOMPUTER\Administrator should have full control.